# Realizar validaciones entre el ViewState y una base de datos

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cordial saludo. En la actualidad tenemos una novedad en el aplicativo que estamos desarrollando, la novedad consiste en que deseamos validar información del ViewState en la pagina web contra información de una base de datos.
La validación consiste en lo siguiente: En el ViewState vamos a almacenar información de montaje y desmontaje de llantas, realizaremos un group by al ViewState para identificar cuantas llantas tienen el estado "montaje" y cuantas llantas tienen el estado "desmontaje". Luego de tener estas cantidades, vamos a tomar dicha información y la vamos a comparar con una base de datos que tiene la cantidad que deben tener dichos estados.
Normalmente, hemos venido utilizando la opcion de ControlToValidate para validar controles del tipo DropDownList, TextBox contra la base de datos y nos a funcionado correctamente, pero teniendo presente que no hay un campo especifico en la pagina web contra el cual validar con la base de datos dichas cantidades, no tenemos idea de como hacerlo. Pensamos hacerlo igual a como lo hemos hecho con los controles de tipo DropDownList y TextBox; obteniendo así los siguientes resultados:

> Código del archivo de tipo ascx

```
<%--Esta es la parte donde se van mostrando y almacenando los registros previso a su insersion en 
        la base de datos.--%>
    <asp:GridView 
        runat="server" 
        ID="GVTabla" 
        CssClass="table" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField 
                HeaderText="IdLlanta" 
                DataField="IdLlanta" 
            />
            <asp:BoundField 
                HeaderText="UbicacionLlanta" 
                DataField="UbicacionLlanta" 
            />
            <asp:BoundField 
                HeaderText="ProfundidadLlanta" 
                DataField="ProfundidadLlanta" 
            />
            <asp:BoundField 
                HeaderText="OperacionLlanta" 
                DataField="OperacionLlanta" 
            />
            <asp:BoundField 
                HeaderText="EstadoLlanta" 
                DataField="EstadoLlanta" 
            />
            <asp:BoundField 
                HeaderText="HorometroEquipo" 
                DataField="HorometroEquipo" 
            />
            <asp:BoundField 
                HeaderText="OdometroEquipo" 
                DataField="OdometroEquipo" 
            />
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <div 
                class="alert alert-info">
                No ha ingresado llantas.
            </div>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
    <td>
        <%--2024-02-28: Validacion de las cantidades de llantas registradas en el ViewState cuya 
            operación fue montaje--%>
        <asp:CustomValidator 
            ErrorMessage="Cantidad Montaje" 
            ControlToValidate="GVTabla" 
            runat="server" 
            ID="CVCantidadMontaje" 
            OnServerValidate="CVCantidadMontaje_ServerValidate" 
            Display="Dynamic" 
            ValidationGroup="Cantidad" 
            ForeColor="Red" 
        />
        <%--2024-02-28: Validacion de las cantidades de llantas registradas en el ViewState cuya 
            operación fue desmontaje--%>
        <asp:CustomValidator 
            ErrorMessage="Cantidad Desmontaje" 
            ControlToValidate="GVTabla" 
            runat="server" 
            ID="CVCantidadDesmontaje" 
            OnServerValidate="CVCantidadDesmontaje_ServerValidate" 
            Display="Dynamic" 
            ValidationGroup="Cantidad" 
            ForeColor="Red" 
        />
    </td>
    <td>
        <%--2024-02-28: Con esto boton valido las cantidades de llantas y realizo la insersion en la base de datos--%>
        <asp:LinkButton 
            Text="Insertar" 
            runat="server" 
            CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" 
            ID="LBValidarInsertar" 
            OnClick="LBValidarInsertar_Click" 
            ValidationGroup="Cantidad" 
        />
    </td>
    <td>
        <%--2024-02-28: Con este boton redirecciono al usuario al informe--%>
        <asp:LinkButton 
            Text="Ir al Informe" 
            runat="server" 
            CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" 
            ID="LBIrInforme" 
            OnClick="LBIrInforme_Click" 
        />
    </td>
```

> Código con el que se hace las validaciones en el archivo tipo ascx.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// 2024-02-28: Valida si la cantidad de llantas registradas en el ViewState cuya operacion es montaje,
/// son iguales a la cantidad reportada en la salida de almacen.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="source"></param>
/// <param name="args"></param>
protected void CVCantidadMontaje_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    // Datos URL
    string Registro = Request["Registro"];
    // Convierto el dato anteior a Int
    int RegistroInt = Convert.ToInt32(Registro);
    // Consulta en la base de datos la cantidad de llantas retiradas de almacen para utlizarlas
    // del lado del cliente.
    var q1 = cliente.GetLlantasSalidasRegistroCantidadAsync(RegistroInt).Result;
    // Le doy el tipo a los datos obtenidos para poder hacer comparaciones posteriormente.
    double CantidadSalida = q1;
    // Datos del metodo
    string operacion = "Montaje";
    // Obtengo la lista del ViewState
    var q2 = from a in Registros
             where
                 a.OperacionLlanta == operacion
             group a by a.OperacionLlanta into GrupoA
             select new CountCargo
             {
                 Cargo = GrupoA.Key,
                 Count = GrupoA.Count()
             };
    var q3 = q2.ToList();
    // Obtengo la cantidad de llantas registradas en el ViewState
    double CantidadViewState = q3.Count;
    // Hacemos la validación
    args.IsValid = (CantidadSalida == CantidadViewState);
}


/// <summary>
/// 2024-02-28: Valida si la cantidad de llantas registradas en el ViewState cuya operacion es montaje,
/// son iguales a la cantidad reportada en la salida de almacen.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="source"></param>
/// <param name="args"></param>
protected void CVCantidadDesmontaje_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    // Datos URL
    string Registro = Request["Registro"];
    // Convierto el dato anteior a Int
    int RegistroInt = Convert.ToInt32(Registro);
    // Consulta en la base de datos la cantidad de llantas retiradas de almacen para utlizarlas
    // del lado del cliente.
    var q1 = cliente.GetLlantasSalidasRegistroCantidadAsync(RegistroInt).Result;
    // Le doy el tipo a los datos obtenidos para poder hacer comparaciones posteriormente.
    double CantidadSalida = q1;
    // Datos del metodo
    string operacion = "Desmontaje";
    // Obtengo la lista del ViewState
    var q2 = from a in Registros
             where
                 a.OperacionLlanta == operacion
             group a by a.OperacionLlanta into GrupoA
             select new CountCargo
             {
                 Cargo = GrupoA.Key,
                 Count = GrupoA.Count()
             };
    var q3 = q2.ToList();
    // Obtengo la cantidad de llantas registradas en el ViewState
    double CantidadViewState = q3.Count;
    // Hacemos la validación
    args.IsValid = (CantidadSalida == CantidadViewState);
}
```

Cuando voy al aplicativo y damos clic al control que lleva a la pagina, inmediatamente sale el error: 503 servicio no disponible.

Luego indagando un poco sobre el error dentro del aplicativo, encontramos la siguiente descripción: No se puede validar el control 'GVTabla' al que hace referencia la propiedad ControlToValidate de 'CVCantidadMontaje'.

Agradecemos su ayuda para aprender a realizar validaciones de este tipo.

Comment: Pero validan contra una grilla??? una grilla no es un control de entrada.. como esperaban hacer la validacion contra eso???

Comment: Hola gbianchi, agradecemos su ayuda si nos puede indicar en un caso como estos, como puedo hacer la validación.

Comment: No soy experto en asp.net, pero no veo la logica de la pantalla que estan tratando de construir (si tengo mas exp en escritorio)... tenes una grilla, y como llenaste esa grilla? en que momento queres validar esa grilla y porque? la grilla deberia servir para mostrar cosas, no para validar, salvo que la grilla sea editable, y en ese caso, quien dispararia el evento de validacion seria la edicion de la celda... no me queda nada claro el escenario.. pero igual, no soy experto y puedo estar confundido...

Comment: La grilla la tenemos para ir ingresando información, el usuario va ingresando llanta por llanta, una vez construye la grilla, el usuario da clic en el boton ValidarInsertar. Debido a que el usuario puede ingresar menos datos de los que realmente debe ingresar, al dar clic en ValidarInsertar, se debe validar que la cantidad de datos sea correcta. La grilla queda almacenada en el ViewState, alli todo los datos, contamos cuantos hay y validamos con una base de datos si la cantidad de datos es correcta. Si es correcta, procedemos a insertarla en el servidor.

Comment: Entonces no necesitan un customvalidator.. Necesitan que el boton, mande los datos, valide, y devuelva a la pantalla si son validos o no.. no usen un control estandar para eso, porque esto que hacen no es estandar...

Comment: Muchas gracias gbianchi por la sugerencia, ya logramos que se quitara el error al dar clic en el botón que nos lleva a la pagina. Seguimos haciendo pruebas pero avanzamos.

Answer (score 0):

Agradecemos a la información brindada por gbianchi. El error lo pudimos corregir al identificar que el CustomValidator lo debíamos implementar al LinkButton de Insertar que habíamos creado y no al GridView, ya que el GridView tiene múltiples celdas y no estaríamos indicándole una celda al decir ControlToValidate="GVTabla". La corrección se realizo en el archivo asxc así:

```
<asp:GridView 
        runat="server" 
        ID="GVTabla" 
        CssClass="table" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField 
                HeaderText="IdLlanta" 
                DataField="IdLlanta" 
            ></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField 
                HeaderText="UbicacionLlanta" 
                DataField="UbicacionLlanta" 
            ></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField 
                HeaderText="ProfundidadLlanta" 
                DataField="ProfundidadLlanta" 
            ></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField 
                HeaderText="OperacionLlanta" 
                DataField="OperacionLlanta" 
            ></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField 
                HeaderText="EstadoLlanta" 
                DataField="EstadoLlanta" 
            ></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField 
                HeaderText="HorometroEquipo" 
                DataField="HorometroEquipo" 
            ></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField 
                HeaderText="OdometroEquipo" 
                DataField="OdometroEquipo" 
            ></asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <div 
                class="alert alert-info">
                No ha ingresado llantas.
            </div>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>

    
    <td>
        <%--2024-02-28: Con esto boton valido las cantidades de llantas y realizo la insersion en la base de datos--%>
        <asp:LinkButton 
            Text="Insertar"
            runat="server"
            CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" 
            ID="LBValidarInsertar" 
            OnClick="LBValidarInsertar_Click" 
            ValidationGroup="Cantidad"> 
            <%--2024-02-28: Validacion de las cantidades de llantas registradas en el ViewState cuya 
            operación fue montaje--%>
            <asp:CustomValidator 
                ErrorMessage=" CantidadMontaje" 
                runat="server" 
                ID="CVCantidadMontaje" 
                OnServerValidate="CVCantidadMontaje_ServerValidate" 
                Display="Dynamic" 
                ValidationGroup="Cantidad" 
                ForeColor="Red" 
            ></asp:CustomValidator>
            <%--2024-02-28: Validacion de las cantidades de llantas registradas en el ViewState cuya 
                operación fue desmontaje--%>
            <asp:CustomValidator 
                ErrorMessage=" CantidadDesmontaje" 
                runat="server" 
                ID="CVCantidadDesmontaje" 
                OnServerValidate="CVCantidadDesmontaje_ServerValidate" 
                Display="Dynamic"
                ValidationGroup="Cantidad" 
                ForeColor="Red"
            ></asp:CustomValidator>
            <%--2024-03-18: Validacion de las ubicaciones registradas en el ViewState. Las ubicaciones 
                de las llantas montadas, deben coincidir con las desmontadas--%>
            <asp:CustomValidator 
                ErrorMessage=" SumaUbicaciones" 
                runat="server" 
                ID="CVSumaUbicaciones" 
                OnServerValidate="CVSumaUbicaciones_ServerValidate" 
                Display="Dynamic"
                ValidationGroup="Cantidad" 
                ForeColor="Red"
            ></asp:CustomValidator>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </td>
```

Como punto importante a mencionar, se indica que debido a que el LinkButton no tiene una celda en particular donde ingresemos datos, no era necesario hacer algo como ControlToValidate="LBValidarInsertar", ya que esto referencia la celda en la pagina y dicha celda no tendría ningún valor a validar. Debido a ello, eliminamos dicha línea del código final.

De esta forma al oprimir el botón, se hace la validación de la cantidad de llantas que era necesaria previamente a la inserción de los datos.